# What is the purpose of using a reference to a reference in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference

In my adventures studying the boost libraries, I've come across function signatures that have parameters which are a reference to a reference to an object.

Example:

```
void function(int && i);
```

What is the purpose/benefit of doing it this way rather than simply taking a reference to an object? I assume there is one if it's in boost.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not a reference to a reference; there is no such thing.

What you're seeing is a C++0x [rvalue reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Rvalue_reference_and_move_semantics), denoted by double ampersands, `&&`. It means that the argument `i` to the function is a temporary, so the function is allowed to clobber its data without causing problems in the calling code.

Example:

```
void function(int &i);  // A
void function(int &&i); // B
int foo();

int main() {
    int x = foo();
    function(x);     // calls A
    function(foo()); // calls B, because the return value is a temporary
}
```

This rarely useful with plain `int`s, but very useful when defining move constructors, for example. A move constructor is like a copy constructor, except that it can safely 'steal' the internal data from the original object, because it's a temporary that will cease to exist after the move constructor returns.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you for the clarification. How is this code in boost (1.42) right now? It's my understanding that boost is currently written for the C++03 standard.

Comment: @Silver: It'll take advantage of features of certain compilers. Some compilers support C++0x (a bit), and if Boost wants to detect and use that, it will.

Comment: @SilverSun: Boost uses conditional compilation (#if, etc.) to customize what's available for each compiler.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a reference to a reference.  It is an rvalue reference, which is a new feature supported by the upcoming C++0x standard.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is an rvalue-reference. It is a new core language feature of C++0x.
See [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html) or less formaly [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Rvalue_reference_and_move_semantics).

The original proposal can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1690.html)